# .DAT file content encoding format

Tags: file, encoding, format

I know that .DAT file's are really not specific to any particular format. I have a few that I'm trying to figure out what type of content is in the file. When in comes to reading encoding's and recognizing stuff like this, I don't have much experience. Can anyone tell me what type of content this is? and maybe how one may convert it to readable text? I feel like these are some sort of ascii/utf8 encoding's maybe? honestly just throwing a dart in the dark there. Just FYI, this is just a question of curiosity around some random .DAT files... nothing specific. I have noticed many different files, when opened in a text editor, looking like this... so, I'm thinking someone may recognize what's going on. *note: there aren't actually double spaces in the file... I added them so the line breaks would show properly in the post.

```
cbb5 910c 3830 9e99 0712 1608 aded f9e2  
b5a3 c6fc b201 109e a091 b492 f6d5 d2cc 
011a 0461 7279 6125 15ac 3d00 283c 3083 
8080 703a 460a 050d e45a b4cd 0a07 0dad  
1919 6010 060a 070d 1c3d 9b7f 1004 0a07
0d44 5392 a410 100a 090d 2b18 b549 1804
```

Not sure if this helps, but the pattern here with 0042 is all over these .dats ... not necessarily those 4 numbers, but the pattern. You'll notice it with the 070d's & 4207's & 0100's as well... a sort of top left to bottom right thing going on... probably doesn't mean anything.

```
0100 1000 4207 0d9f 1901 0010 0042 070d
1d1a 0100 1000 4207 0d7d 1901 0010 0042
070d 13cc 0100 1000 4207 0d22 1c01 0010
0042 070d 141e 0100 1000 4207 0d62 1b01
0010 0042 070d 611c 0100 1000 4207 0dd0
1502 0010 0042 070d c239 0100 1000 4207
0dd4 6c01 0010 0042 070d 9021 0100 1000
4207 0df3 df00 0010 0042 070d b831 0100
1000 4207 0dba 3101 0010 0042 070d f7df
0000 1000 4207 0df9 df00 0010 0042 070d
c0db 0100 1000 4207 0dfb df00 0010 0042
070d 9b6d 0100 1000 4207 0df4 6d01 0010
```

Comment: Doesn't look like anything I've seen, nor is there an identifiable magic number.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ... I'm thinking dev's use 8 groups of 4 characters per line in many different ways, and each is different... maybe that's why I've seen that pattern a lot in files like this, but they all mean/translate to different things.